# Compare times in calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I want to compare the time from a column called "Date and time" (datetime format) with a fixed time value. I have created a calculated column for this.

```
=IF(AND(TIME([Date and time])>TIMEVALUE("06:00:00");TIME([Date and time])<TIMEVALUE("18:00:00");"Day";"Night"))
```

It works when I use the HOUR() function, but I want to be able to use specific minutes.

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following formulas:

```
=IF(AND(TIME(HOUR([Date and time]),MINUTE([Date and time]),SECOND([Date and time]))>TIMEVALUE("06:00:00"),TIME(HOUR([Date and time]),MINUTE([Date and time]),SECOND([Date and time]))<TIMEVALUE("18:00:00")),"Day","Night")
```